# How to hide Authorization headers using Spring boot and Angular app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

I have implemented JWT Authentication using Spring security. Since the Authorization header is visible in the browser an attacker can manipulate the data using token that which is present in the Authorization header. Is there any way to restrict this. I am using Spring boot and Angular 8. Any help is appreciated.

Example for data manipulation
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you use cookie for the same

Comment: you mean an authenticated user become an attacker? unless there is no way to get a token.
For an attacker, since you have produced a token using a secret key in your server, unless and until the key is public; access token cannot be forged.
Also if an authenticated user is doing the same, your application should have strict validation on a data manipulation request. Like the owner of the record which going to get updated is actually the logged in user(from access token).

Comment: @YashRami, can you please give any reference so that it will be helpfull.

Comment: @MidhunMohan, do you mean for valid user we cannot restrict this.

Comment: @Jayanth yes, for a valid user we cannot restrict, if they open the developer tools in the browser they can inspect as every developer normally do. Because the client needs to send at least some information to server from browser for authorization and those details will be able to inspect on the developer console of every browser.

Comment: Do you mean HEADER or URL? Can you show the header data and give an example of a successful manipulation?

Comment: @michaeak, I have updated question. Can you please check.

Comment: @Jayanth I have written a high-level answer.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can never trust a client. You have to deal with manipulated data.

This means you always have to validate the clients requests, no matter what.

On a high level, there are many solutions to this kind of problem.

1) In case of created-by, for me this is a typical not-updatable field, because who created something never changes.

1a) in JPA a column can be annotated with `updatable=false` so this will always be disregarded for a merge operation.

1b) another option would be first to load the item from memory and only use attributes from the request that you allow to be saved for this business case, copy the allowed values over to the loaded item and merge the loaded item to the database.

2.) in other cases, for example for an updated-by field you need to cross check if the authenticated user matches the updated-by id. if not raise an exception/401 whatever.

3.) This one is going more to your solution I guess. I also suggest to not transfer your whole data that is stored for an item, rather use Transfer Objects or Use Case Objects. Using transfer objects or use case objects it virtually hides data, because you only transfer dedicated data. This is also a security recommendation because some data you just don't want to show to anyone, so if you hide them on the client-side but if it is already sent to the client an experienced user can always make data visible by inspection or manipulation. Just imagine you send salary information about a person every time you display a person ...
A broadly used solution to map data objects to transfer objects and back is the mapstruct library.

Hope this helps to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide information from the Browser. It is a client-server communication so the user can always explore page HTML content or Http headers or request parameter using dev tools.

The way to secure your communication is using [Https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) (so content including headers is encrypted) and also using a short time leaving JWT token (by using expiration date and refresh token) so it is harder to the attacker to impersonate someone.

Comment: we are using Https. Still we are facing this issue.Will https hide Authorization header? Alreday token will be encrypted.

Comment: Https will encrypted both headers and request/response content, no point to encrypt your token if your application is already using https, double encryption is not "safer" is just unnecessary complexity. 

Http communication security is not related to what user can see can not see in it browser is about how this information is transmitted.